# LISP - Converting a string with the representation of an array to an array

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a file which has an bi-dimensional array in each line. I'm having trouble finding a way of parsing the file into actual arrays and them putting them in a list.

the file looks like this, the arrays are in different lines, even though it does not seem to:
[image: file with matrixes]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just open the file for reading using `with-open-file` and then use the function `read` as often as you would like or as often as there are arrays. Each `read` returns an array. Using `loop` you can *collect* them into a list.

Basically something like this:

```
(with-open-file (s filename)
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
    (loop with eof = '#:eof
          for object = (read s nil eof)
          until (eq object eof)
          collect object)))
```

Note also that it does not matter whether each array is on its own line. It would still work if they are on one line. A *newline* between expressions is just *whitespace* for the Lisp *reader*.

Comment: Thank you! so much easier that I thought :)

Comment: @LidiaFreitas: that's because the array is already printed in Common Lisp syntax. :-)

Comment: … and always bind `*read-eval*` to `nil` before `read`ing from untrusted sources.

Comment: @Svante: good advice. I've added that. That's probably where the language should be changed, or where a standard macro `with-secure-io-syntax` (as opposed to `cl:with-standard-io-syntax`) is needed.